# Ways to Neutralize Firearms

Tags: science-fiction, firearms, mechs, guns

I am trying to write a sci-fi story in the near future where armies use mechas but I also want them to engage in close combat using swords.
Here is what I came up with so far:
An army could use an EMP thus rendering the mechas and laser guns ineffective.
But what about traditional firearms...they could still resort to that.
My question is how can one neutralize all these classical weapons from guns to grenades?

Comment: This looks like a very open ended question. Can you [edit] this so that you're asking for help with a specific problem rather than just asking for the general thoughts and opinions of the members of this site.

Comment: Do we need a new "no-firearms" tag for this kind of questions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent guns from working?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/202526/how-to-prevent-guns-from-working)

Comment: i think if you really want to disable classical firearms, you can only handwave it (like stargate did in one episode)

Comment: Dune this this by giving personal shields, which block fast moving projectiles. Sword moving slowly penetrate them.

Comment: @Alexander most of these get closed as duplicates anyway

Comment: It is also worth considering that a laser doesn't necessarily need delicate electronic components in order to function. "EMP" is often waved about like an anti-technological magic wand, but it has very definite limits.

Comment: You can't use an EMP without disabling the Mech. You can't ignore firearms because the tech to build a mech requires the tech to build a firearm. What that really leaves you with is some kind of attrition - you don't have the economy/resources to supply firearms, it's all you can do to keep the mechs running. The result is hand-to-hand combat.

Answer (score 4):

### Frame challenge, You can't

firearms are just to mechanically and chemically simple to prevent as long as chemistry and metallurgy exist as sciences.

this is why any technological setting that does not use firearms resorts to magic or technology indistinguishable from magic to prevent them.

Answer (score 0):

**They don't have any firearms.**

And they don't know how to make them.  Or anything else.  These warriors are *users* of technology.  They invent nothing.  They can barely repair the things that they use, with "repair" meaning "wipe down".  The different group who originally made these fighting mechas have nothing to do with the people who are currently using them.  Maybe the makers were a long time ago.  Maybe the makers are from some central empire and do not care that the people using their old mechs want firearms and cannot build any themselves.

The people who are fighting in this story actually have no skills to speak of except bloodthirstiness.  Their metal weapons are pieces of broken machines that they have taken off and sharpened up on rocks.  Armor is likewise improvised from what is available; pants stuffed with rocks is a favorite.  These warriors do not know how to farm, or even cook; with the mechas they have come into possession of many ready-to-eat meals and they subsist on those.

Pretty much it is fighting for this bunch.  Also bragging about fighting.  Not gun making.

Comment: if they can't fix anything the tech will not last long, as in probably not a generation.

Comment: @John - yes.  But a generation is more than enough time for plenty of war.

Answer (score -3):

**They don't have access to gunpowder or smokeless powder or any other propellants used to make ammunition**

Maybe every scrap of sulfur is desperately needed for some vital technology and they can't spare any to make gunpowder. Maybe all the sulfur on Earth was destroyed in some sort of runaway freak chemical reaction. Maybe the story takes place on another planet where the ingredients for gunpowder/whatever other powder can't be found.

Whatever the pretext, the chemicals necessary to manufacture administration simply isn't available in your story, eliminating firearms as a weapon of war.

Comment: you don't need gunpowder to make firearms, in fact most modern firearms don't use gunpowder.

Comment: the chemicals needed for firearms are so widespread that would be impossible, even if they didn't exist you'd most likely prevent life from existing bc you'd remove several chemicals needed for that